# Custom posts don't work

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, plugin-development

I made a basic custom post type basing on examples from codex but it doesn't work until I modify permalink settings.
When I click `view` to preview the post I see `Not found` notification but when I modify permalink settings, click `Save changes` the post works as well as default post type. I mean, without creating special loop queries.

What should I do to avoid this error creating a theme to public use or selling?
Do everyone will have to change permalink settings to be able to use my custom post types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After custom post type registration, that is `register_post_type()` , try adding function `flash_rewrite_rules();`

This will automatically flush all rewrite rules so you won't need to go to permalink settings each time.

See this page: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Flushing_Rewrite_on_Activation

Example:

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_cpt_init' );
function my_cpt_init() {
    register_post_type( ... );
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
```

As it's said in the docs, it's better to do that on plugin activation.

Comment: flash or flush ??

Comment: @SanjokGurung Flush is correct.